# Where is the location of custom GroupTemplate?

Tags: ribbon

I am in the process creating the webpart associated ribbon following the example. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552606.aspx
I would like to create my own GroupTemplate. However it seams I cannot find the location in the Elements.xml to put the definition. I tried inside

Answer (score 3):

Location for ribbon group templates is `Ribbon.Templates._children`. For example:

```
<CustomAction Id="MyRibbonCustomization" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
        <CommandUIDefinitions>
            <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Templates._children">
                <GroupTemplate Id="Ribbon.Templates.MyCustomGroupTemplate">
                    <!-- your group template definition goes here -->
                </GroupTemplate>
            </CommandUIDefinition>
        </CommandUIDefinitions>
    </CommandUIExtension>
</CustomAction>
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to cover what you need:

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/customizing-ribbon-part-1-creating-tabs.html